# Apache httpd mod_proxy_html does not parse style attribute

Tags: proxy, apache-2.4, html

I have here a very strange problem with mod_proxy_html. The HTML code which gets parsed looks like this:

```
<a href="/old/something.html" style="background-image:url('/old/images/background.png')">link</a>
```

Our configuration looks like this:

```
ProxyPass /  ajp://localhost:9000/webapp/
<Location />
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
ProxyPassReverse /
ProxyHTMLExtended On

ProxyHTMLURLMap /old/ /new/

RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
</Location>
```

And in the module config file I added this:

```
ProxyHTMLLinks  a               href style
```

From my understanding this should now filter the HREF and the STYLE attribute. But it only filters the HREF. Can anybody explain me why?

It is the httpd version 2.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to wrap the `ProxyHTMLLinks` directive within a `<Location />...</Location>`, the same as `ProxyHTMLURLMap`.  When `ProxyHTMLURLMap` is invoked, it may override your previous `ProxyHTMLLinks a` directive with a default version that rewrites `href` but not `style`.

Comment: Sadly no. I tried it now and it didn't change anything at all.